# How to draw a polygon in C++ such that the lines do not intersect?

Tags: c++, polygon, computational-geometry

I need to draw a polygon in C++.  I set random points in vector and then connect them via lines. But sometimes those lines intersect and i get something like this.

[image]

Is there any formula or something like that, so that the lines wouldn't cross?

Here is part of the code:

```
void draw_picture(Canvas & canvas) {
  PairXY a,b,c,d,e;
  int k;
  vector <PairXY> vertex;
  vertex.push_back(PairXY(drandom(k),drandom(k)));
  vertex.push_back(PairXY(drandom(k),drandom(k)));
  vertex.push_back(PairXY(drandom(k),drandom(k)));
  vertex.push_back(PairXY(drandom(k),drandom(k)));
  vertex.push_back(PairXY(drandom(k),drandom(k)));

  vector <PairXY>::const_iterator iter;

  iter = vertex.begin();
  a=*iter;
  iter = vertex.begin()+1;
  b=*iter;
  iter = vertex.begin()+2;
  c=*iter;
  iter = vertex.begin()+3;
  d=*iter;
  iter = vertex.begin()+4;
  e=*iter;

  Line l1(a,b);
  draw_line(l1,canvas);
  Line l2(b,c);
  draw_line(l2,canvas);
  Line l3(c,d);
  draw_line(l3,canvas);
  Line l4(d,e);
  draw_line(l4,canvas);
  Line l5(e,a);
  draw_line(l5,canvas);
}
```

Comment: You might like to learn about **loops**...

Comment: There can be multiple polygons formed from a set of points. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are probably looking for is a "Simple" (as opposed to "Complex") Polygon:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon

There's not necessarily a unique solution to that:

[Sort point list into polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755938/sort-point-list-into-polygon)

This is why the ordering of points or path segments typically matters in polygon drawing engines.  If you are so inclined--however--you can find *at least one* non-complex polygon for a set of points:

http://www.computational-geometry.org/mailing-lists/compgeom-announce/2003-March/000727.html

http://www.computational-geometry.org/mailing-lists/compgeom-announce/2003-March/000732.html

---

Others have pointed out your code is repetitive as written.  You also don't define `k` in the excerpt you shared, and it's better to use a plural term for a vector of objects ("vertices") rather than one suggesting it is singular ("vertex").  Here's one fairly simple-to-understand set of changes that should generalize to any number of vertices:

```
void draw_picture(Canvas & canvas, int k, int numVertices = 5) {
  vector<PairXY> vertices;
  for (int index = 0; index < numVertices; index++) { 
      vertices.push_back(PairXY(drandom(k),drandom(k)));
  }

  vector<PairXY>::const_iterator iter = vertices.begin();
  while (iter != vertices.end()) {
     PairXY startPoint = *iter;
     iter++;
     if (iter == vertices.end()) {
         Line edgeLine (startPoint, vertices[0]);
         draw_line(edgeLine, canvas);
     } else {
         Line edgeLine (startPoint, *iter);
         draw_line(edgeLine, canvas);
     }
   }
}
```

There are a lot of ways to manage iterations in C++, although many of them are more verbose than their counterparts in other languages.  Recently a nice [range-based `for` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for-loop) was added in C++11, but your build environment may not support it yet.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

As far as calculating them goes, you have [several options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).

I've had good luck with [the monotone chain algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain#C.2B.2B).

Comment: That would guarantee no crossing lines, but it would prevent e.g. star shapes.

Answer (score 0):

sort the array before drawing it

Find the left most point
than go CCW from there

ie 
leftmost where point y < first point y until none found

rightmost point until none found

Comment: the origin here could be described as the point at the middle of the line that connects the leftmost and rightmost point,